# Как получить правильный выбор в AutoCompleteTextView используя свой адаптер

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Как получить правильный выбор в AutoCompleteTextView используя свой адаптер
Есть AutoCompleteTextView

```
((AutoCompleteTextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.name_et)).append(((ArrayDictionary) itemsDictionary.get(positionShop)).getName());
AdapterAutoComplite adapterAutoComplite = new AdapterAutoComplite(this, mWord);
        editTextNameStreet.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplite);
```

Есть класс данных для отображения в выпадающем списке

```
public class ArrayWordShopping {

    String name;
    String price;...
```

Есть адаптер

```
public class AdapterAutoComplite extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<ArrayWordShopping> mResults;
    private List<ArrayWordShopping> mResFromFilter;

    public AdapterAutoComplite(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayWordShopping> mylist) {
        mContext = context;
        mResults = mylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResFromFilter.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayWordShopping getItem(int index) {
        return mResFromFilter.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_2line, parent, false);
        }
        ArrayWordShopping wordShopping = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(wordShopping.getName());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(wordShopping.getPrice());

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                //temporarylist = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                Log.i("tester", "publishResults: " + constraint + " " + results);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<ArrayWordShopping> FilteredList = new ArrayList<ArrayWordShopping>();
                Log.i("tester", "performFiltering: " + constraint);

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    results.values = mResults;
                    results.count = mResults.size();
                } else {
                    mResFromFilter = new ArrayList<ArrayWordShopping>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mResults.size(); i++) {
                        if (mResults.get(i).getName().indexOf("" + constraint) > -1) {
                            FilteredList.add(mResults.get(i));
                            mResFromFilter.add(mResults.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = FilteredList;
                    results.count = FilteredList.size();
                }

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

ПРОБЛЕМА в том, что при выборе пользователем значения из списка фильтра (Т.е. выбрали хлеб цена 2р) а получил на activity в AutoCompleteTextView строку вида com.ххххххххххххх.us.shop2.data.ArrayWordShopping@8106e8f  Как правильно получать данные по отдельности товар и цена? 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Либо в классе `ArrayWordShopping` переопределить метод `toString()`

```
public class ArrayWordShopping {

    String name;
    String price;...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return name + price;
    }

}
```

2) Либо вызвать метод на AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener и брать нужный элемент и ручками все ставить, как Вам нужно

```
AutoCompleteTextView editTextNameStreet = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.name_et);
        final AdapterAutoComplite adapterAutoComplite = new AdapterAutoComplite(this, mWord);
        editTextNameStreet.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplite);
        editTextNameStreet.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayWordShopping instance = adapter.getNeededItemByPosition(posititon);
                //Делаем что хотим с editTextNameStreet
            }
        });
```