# обработка выбора AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Задача такая. Выбирается некоторый элемент из списка. Например есть там "кот, кошка". пишу "ко" выбираю "кошка", т.е. нажимаю на пункт "кошка", как обработать этот выбор? Вот нажал на кошку и мне нужно после этого совершить действие.

и другой вопрос, как совершать действия при наборе каждой буквы?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606437/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать TextWatcher.

```
messageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            //вызывается перед именением поля
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            //вызывается при изменении текста
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                            //вызывается после того, как текст был изменён
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить текст выбираемого пункта нужно повесить слушатель

```
 autocompletetv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```